# Read/Write File in blackberry

Tags: java, file, blackberry

I am writing to a file using this code.

```
        protected void writeFile(String text) {
            DataOutputStream os = null;
            FileConnection fconn = null;
                try {
                    fconn = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///store/home/user/documents/file.txt", Connector.READ_WRITE);
                    if (!fconn.exists())
                        fconn.create();
                    os = fconn.openDataOutputStream();
                    os.write(text.getBytes());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (null != os)
                            os.close();
                        if (null != fconn)
                            fconn.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
            }}
```

the code is working fine.

My problem is if I write first time "Banglore" and when I read it, I get "Banglore".
But, second time when I write "India" and when I read it, I get, "Indialore". 
so, basically  its content is not changing according the text , I am giving.
Please tell me how to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

writing in a file doesn't remove the content but it just replaces the content, so writing 'india' over 'Bangalore' will replace the 'Banga' with 'India' and the rest would remain the same. If you want to completely remove old content with newer one, you need to [truncate()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/javax/microedition/io/file/FileConnection.html#truncate%28long%29)
the file from where the newer data ends. `truncate(text.getBytes().length)`